# How to get a good score on Google PageSpeed Insights with Google Visualization API

Tags: google-visualization, pagespeed

I am trying to get a good score with [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), on [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), but keep getting message like this:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>   Your page has 2 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in
>   rendering your page. Approximately 49% of the above-the-fold content
>   on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following
>   resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking
>   resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly
>   in the HTML. Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
>   **https://www.gstatic.com/charts/44/css/util/util.css
>   https://www.gstatic.com/charts/44/css/core/tooltip.css**

The strange thing is that these two files are actually loaded after rendering has started (according to [webpagetest.org](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/160825_V9_CV4/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1)). So are these files really blocking the rendering process?

Did anyone manage to get a good score while using google charts? My current score is 51 for mobile and 93 for desktop. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at request numbers 22 and 37
Kind of humorous that it is Google's CSS that is causing the problem.
request 22 is where first paint begins.  But that is a mistake because the Browser did not see request 37 coming down the pike.
All CSS and font files must be linked in before any JS.
When the Browser encountered request 37 it had to re-start rendering. The Browser needs all CSS and fonts before it can begin rendering. 
 
Notice how the DOM loaded (purple vertical line) occurs right after request 37 is loaded.
JS does not belong in the `<head>`, it should be placed after the HTML just before the `</body>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The JavaScript is all called async. So it should not be a problem I suppose. I placed most css in <style> tags and refer to a a single css  (request 37) file at the end just before the </html> tag. The advantage of this approach is that the rendering can begin already before the full page is processed. However Google PageSpeed does not seem to agree and indicates request 37 should be done even later ?!?

Comment: My answer was based solely on the waterfall.  I did not view the page.  Google came to the same conclusion.  Your page is too complex for Google's assessment.  If it were my site I'd find a way to make the "loading" icons unnecessary.  I'd create the page with a server side script (e.g. python, php) rather than JavaScript.  There is way too much JS and CSS in this page.